# Retrieving Recipient Status via REST API

Tags: docusignapi

There appears to be two ways I can gather status information about individual recipients on an envelope:

1. GET - v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/recipients
2. GET - v2/accounts/:accountId/envelopes/:envelopeId/audit_events

Unfortunately, each of these suffers from a separate limitation that is making it difficult for me to use either.

1. This API call returns two DateTime values of interest:  deliveredDateTime and signedDateTime.  I am able to call and use this API successfully.  However, it appears to me that deliveredDateTime is not specified until the user actually clicks the email link AND clicks the review documents button on the signer view.  Since what I was actually interested in might be better described as sentDateTime, deliveredDateTime doesn't appear to work for my needs.
2. This API call returns a detailed list of all events that have transpired on the envelope, including individual receipient status updates.  However, the data format is such that in order to tie the result data back to recipients, I have to do string matches on the recipient name.  I'd prefer to do the match based on email or, better still, recipientID, but the audit log entries for "sent invitations" and "signed" don't contain these fields.  Here is an example ([click here to view larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMs0M.jpg)):

[image]

Is there an API call other than these two that I can use?  Is there a way to get additional data in the audit event API call?

Thank you in advance,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to get additional data from the audit_events call since the DocuSign API documentation (which is up to date) indicates that call has no parameters (other than the envelopeId in the URL).

I think you're stuck with doing a string comparison on the `userName` value to identify/link your recipients, however I want to point out that once you do that you can then link to their unique `recipientGuid` through the first api call you've highlighted here.

For instance, the **/audit_events** API call seems to achieve what you want and has all the info you need, however it identifies the recipients through their userNames.  If you then make a call on the *same* envelope and check the response from the **/recipients** URI, it contains the `name`, `email`, `recipientId`, and `recipientGuid` for each and every recipient in the envelope.  Match the user names and you now have access to their IDs, etc.

So in the end I don't believe there's one API call to achieve this but you can solve by doing one string compare and combining the results from the API calls you've highlighted.

Comment: I need the invitation date and the signature date.  My audit log parser will work though, provided the formatting of the various output columns remain constant.  However, when a user signs on a mobile device the information column (usually blank when the action column equals "signed") contains "on mobile" instead.  This kind of variation in the message column could break my parser.  Why do the audit logs lack unique IDs?  Or, why does the recipient information API lack the date the invitation was sent?

Comment: If the current functionality offered through the API does not suit your needs then please log a change/feature request through your DocuSign Account Manager.